# Chapterbib with lyx

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

I used `chapterbib` package to obtain bibliography by chapter in latex but now i need to use it with LyX 1.6.8

I read the documentation presented in http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Tips and recomended to use an Perl script named `bibtexall`, and changed the output for LyX and `bibtex` to `bibtexall`.

The steps that I used are

1. Download the Perl script
2. install strawberry-perl-5.16.2.1-32bit
3. Run the file.lyx, i obtain the file.pdf with all the configurations, but no obtain the references by chapter

My question is how to use this Perl script and what is the path to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, one would invoke a `perl` script using the following syntax from command line: `perl perl_script.pl [options]`. In your case I would assume this should be something like `perl bibtexall.pl my_file.lyx`. I'm saying *assume* because: 1. I haven't used `chapterbib` so far and 2. the link actually mentions a `python` script not a `perl` script. If you open that script in a text editor you will find the following instructions from the author:

> # Place this file somewhere in your PATH , then
>   # open Tools->Preferences->LaTeX in LyX and change
>   # the "bibtex command" from "bibtex" to "bibtexall".

have you tried that?

Comment: I will prove it, i´m sorry is a pythoh script.